# Why can you put a function prototype inside a function?

Tags: c++, function-prototypes

Sometimes I write code like the following

```
struct Bob
{
    Bob() {}
};

int main()
{
    Bob b();
}
```

What I wanted to do is create an object b, using Bob's default constructor. To fix it, I have to remove the brackets after b. It turns out the compiler interprets the line as a function prototype otherwise!

Ok, I can understand that to follow the rule. But why can you put a function prototype inside a function anyway? What is the purpose?

Comment: It's just a normal declaration (no matter how [vexing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse) it is). You have to differ between *declarations* and *definitions* in C++.

Comment: Because then the standard would be even longer.

Comment: But WHY? I am sure the compiler can know when it is inside a function body and therefore select the other interpretation.

Comment: @Rapptz Thanks :) It's not like OP mentioned it already in his question.

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen Ah.. I'm not reading well enough today. Sorry.

Comment: @NeilKirk What if you overload `operator()` in your class? How would you expect the compiler to know the difference between calling `operator()` and constructing the class itself using that syntax?

Comment: @NeilKirk I'm sure you can make a compiler that knows. But this is a feature of the c++ compiler your using.

Comment: Other than 'the standard says so', and it does so because the C standard allowed it before, I don't think you will find a good reason to allow this.

Comment: @Rapptz: `operator()` could never be called like that.

Answer (score 2):

Presumably because in C that syntax had no other possible meaning (no member functions or constructors) so they specified it to be a function declaration.

Then when C++ inherited the functionality from C they couldn't change the meaning of such a construct without risking the breakage of existing code.

If you're asking why they allow local function-declarations at all, that may be because they wanted to allow for functions to be scoped as closely to use as possible, or it may just be lost to time.